# JAVA how to use CreateProcess Function

Tags: java

This is what I've got From C++

```
String pathexe = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
String command= "notepad.exe";

if(!CreateProcess(
        pathexe.c_str(),  // lpApplicationName
        command.c_str(),  // lpCommandLine
        NULL,   // lpProcessAttributes
        NULL,   // lpThreadAttributes
        FALSE,  // bInheritHandles
        0,      // dwCreationFlags
        NULL,   // lpEnvironment
        NULL,   // lpCurrentDirectory
        &si,    // lpStartupInfo
        &pi     // lpProcessInformation
        ))
```

i m trying to search CreateProcess used in JAVA language, it is JAVA possible to use CreateProcess?

i need the `lpProcessInformation.hThread` & `lpProcessInformation.hProcess` return value.

Comment: look for `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @nullpointer i need the lpProcessInformation.hThread return value, processbuilder possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

try `Runtime` and `Process` object.

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start dir ");
    BufferedWriter writeer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    writeer.write("dir");
    writeer.flush();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read output of ur commaand
```

Comment: so how to get lpStartupInfo and lpProcessInformation return value? inside the writeer?

Comment: Can u share, exact command that you run in command promot, and the response u get back? are u looking for process id?

Comment: Not for process id, it is thread id and hprocess is something similiar process id